# Selected value in asp.net dropdown in a repeater not returned

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've currently go a very strange problem.  I'm using an asp.net wizard to upload some files.  The files are uploaded using plupload.  After the files have uploaded I have a list of the upload files stored in a session variable.  I use the session variable to create a table showing the upload files.  The user now has option to set a file category using a dropdown in the table.  When the user clicks 'finish' button the code reads the list of files and the category from the table.  The odd thing is this code works fine on my development machine and on several servers but on a particular clients server the drop down value always returns as null.  Here is the relevent code:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            bindRepeater();         
    } 

private void bindRepeater()
    {
        ArrayList sessionFiles = (ArrayList)Session["PLUploadFiles"];

        IList<document> files = new List<document>();

        foreach (string fileName in sessionFiles)
        {
            document doc = new document();

            doc.FileName = fileName;
            doc.Description = fileName.Split('.').First();

            files.Add(doc);
        }

        TableRepeater.DataSource = files;
        TableRepeater.DataBind();
    }

protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in TableRepeater.Items)
        {
            Label descriptionLabel = (Label) item.FindControl("DescriptionLabel");
            String description = descriptionLabel.Text;

            Label fileNameLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("FileNameLabel");
            String fileName = fileNameLabel.Text;

            DropDownList categoryDropDown = (DropDownList) item.FindControl("CategoryDropDownList");
            string category = categoryDropDown.SelectedValue;

            if(SaveClicked != null)
            {
                SaveEventArgs s = new SaveEventArgs();
                s.FileName = fileName;
                s.Category = category;
                s.Description = description;

                SaveClicked(this, s);
            }

        }

        Response.Redirect(RedirectURL);
    }
```

Note that the entire wizard lives on a usercontrol.  Has anybody got any idea why this code works fine on most machines but fails on one particular server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've fixed it.  For some reason I was seeing a double postback.  This was calling my code to reset the session variables in Page_Load at the wrong time. The work around is to reset the session variables in the page that links to the upload page so they are reset before the page is loaded.  I've no idea why I'm seeing the double postback.

Comment: Is the 'finish' button a link button? What does the rendered HTML for the 'finish' button look like?